# Inject mock bean into AnnotatinConfigApplicationContext failed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, spring-test

My Springboot application doesn't have a main class as it has a AWS Lambda handler.

This is what my classtobetested looks like.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "${spring.basepackages}")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class AWSLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<LambdaRequest, LambdaResponse> {

    @Override
    public LambdaResponse handleRequest(LambdaRequest input, Context context) {

        GenericResponse serviceResponse = new GenericResponse();
        LambdaResponse lambdaResponse = new LambdaResponse();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            AnnotationConfigApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
            ServiceClass service = applicationContext.getBean(ServiceClassImpl.class);
            serviceResponse = service.process(input);
            lambdaResponse.setBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(serviceResponse));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Exception occured in Handler-" + e.getMessage());
            //Setting error codes and messages for the response
        } 
        return lambdaResponse;
    }
}
```

My Config class looks like this

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "${spring.basepackages}")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Config{
    //No additional code here.
}
```

My Testclass will look like this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Config.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class LambdaHandlerTest{

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private AWSLambdaHandler handler;

    @MockBean
    private GenericResponse genericResponse;

    @MockBean
    ServiceClass mockService;

    @MockBean
    ServiceImpl mockServiceImpl;

    @MockBean
    Context context;


    @Test
    public void testHandleRequest_success() {
        when(mockService.getOrdersList(any())).thenReturn(genericResponse);
        LambdaResponse response = handler.handleRequest(createRequest(), context);
    }

    private LambdaRequest createRequest() {
        LambdaRequest request = new LambdaRequest();
        request.setCustomerNo(TestUtils.CUSTOMER_NO);
        request.setOpco(TestUtils.OPCO);
        request.setOrderNo(TestUtils.ORDER_NO);
        request.setUomOrderNo(TestUtils.UOM_ORDER_NO);
        return request;
    }
}
```

In the above class I am creating the MockBean for the service class and hoping it will get injecting when I run my test case but in reality a real object is being created for the service class so my Mock Stubs are not working and eventually I end up with an exception. Can someone please suggest what can be done.

Comment: Ofcourse it won't inject as you are creating a new application context yourself.. Why are you doing this? The service should be created by the `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class already due to component scanning, you are basically starting the whole application again... Just use depenency inject as you should and then it will work.

Comment: You mean, if I tried Autowired annotation to get the bean in the handler class instead of using the ApplicationContext, that way I can get my mockBean out there?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to hard to work around Spring Boot / Spring Cloud Function.

First of all your function should look something like this.

```
@Slf4j
@SpringBootApplication
public class AWSLambdaHandler implements RequestHandler<LambdaRequest, LambdaResponse> {

    private final ServiceClass service;

    public AWSLambdaHandler(ServiceClas service) {
      this.service=service;
    }

    @Override
    public LambdaResponse handleRequest(LambdaRequest input, Context context) {

        GenericResponse serviceResponse = new GenericResponse();
        LambdaResponse lambdaResponse = new LambdaResponse();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            serviceResponse = service.process(input);
            lambdaResponse.setBody(mapper.writeValueAsString(serviceResponse));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("Exception occured in Handler-" + e.getMessage());
            //Setting error codes and messages for the response
        } 
        return lambdaResponse;
    }
}
```

Next ditch your `Config` class as that doesn't add anything (or at least remove all the annotations except `@Configuration`.

Then rewrite your test as trying to create a mock for the response etc. doesn't make sense nor do you need MockMVC.

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class LambdaHandlerTest{

    @Autowired
    private AWSLambdaHandler handler;

    @MockBean
    private ServiceClass mockService;

    @MockBean
    private Context context;

    @Test
    public void testHandleRequest_success() {
        when(mockService.getOrdersList(any())).thenReturn(genericResponse);
        LambdaResponse response = handler.handleRequest(createRequest(), context);
    }

    private LambdaRequest createRequest() {
        LambdaRequest request = new LambdaRequest();
        request.setCustomerNo(TestUtils.CUSTOMER_NO);
        request.setOpco(TestUtils.OPCO);
        request.setOrderNo(TestUtils.ORDER_NO);
        request.setUomOrderNo(TestUtils.UOM_ORDER_NO);
        return request;
    }
}
```

This should work like you want. However you could even write a simple unit test now (due to the constructor injection usedin the `AWSLambdaHandler` and you wouldn't need Spring at all.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class LambdaHandlerTest{

    @InjectMocks
    private AWSLambdaHandler handler;

    @Mock
    private ServiceClass mockService;

    @Mock
    private Context context;

    @Test
    public void testHandleRequest_success() {
        when(mockService.getOrdersList(any())).thenReturn(genericResponse);
        LambdaResponse response = handler.handleRequest(createRequest(), context);
    }

    private LambdaRequest createRequest() {
        LambdaRequest request = new LambdaRequest();
        request.setCustomerNo(TestUtils.CUSTOMER_NO);
        request.setOpco(TestUtils.OPCO);
        request.setOrderNo(TestUtils.ORDER_NO);
        request.setUomOrderNo(TestUtils.UOM_ORDER_NO);
        return request;
    }
}
```

This last one will run a lot faster as it is just a simple Unit test, while the `@SpringBootTest` is more of an integration test.